# Golang coverprofile output format

Tags: testing, go, cover

I'm trying to make sense of the `-coverprofile cover.out` option in `go test`, specifically the format of the file.

Covering `server.go` for example, yields the output in `cover.out`:

```
mode: set
github.com/cnuss/api_server/server.go:47.2,48.16 2 0
github.com/cnuss/api_server/server.go:52.2,53.16 2 0
github.com/cnuss/api_server/server.go:57.2,58.16 2 0
github.com/cnuss/api_server/server.go:62.2,63.16 2 0
github.com/cnuss/api_server/server.go:67.2,68.16 2 0
github.com/cnuss/api_server/server.go:72.2,73.16 2 0
github.com/cnuss/api_server/server.go:77.2,78.16 2 0
```

1. What do each of the different columns mean?
2. Is the format of the output in a "standard" format, e.g. gcov, xunit, etc. and convertable to another format?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The golang-nuts community (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/golang-nuts) provided a couple useful tools for converting Go coverage into more useful formats.

JUnit Format (for summarizing test executions):

```
# Prerequisites
go install github.com/jstemmer/go-junit-report/v2@latest
# Tests
go test -v 2>&1 ./... | go-junit-report -set-exit-code > report.xml
```

Cobertura Format (for detailing code coverage):

```
# Prerequisites
go get github.com/axw/gocov/gocov
go get github.com/AlekSi/gocov-xml
# Coverage
go test -coverprofile=cover.out
gocov convert cover.out | gocov-xml > coverage.xml
```

The thread that pointed me in this direction was here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/iUc68Zrxk_c

Comment: How is this the accepted answer? It doesn't answer the question!

Comment: @SamJones First time?

Answer (score 61):

The fields are:

```
name.go:line.column,line.column numberOfStatements count
```

[Source](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/0104a31b8fbcbe52728a08867b26415d282c35d2/src/cmd/cover/profile.go#L56)

Comment: From a recent research I found that the last field is actually a 0/1 flag that tells whether the specified statements are covered or not

Comment: Thank you, I finally found what I was looking for.

Comment: Re: @Tareq Sha, I just had a look at go 1.15.2 and the last field had values that weren't 0/1, count seems more likely

Comment: @TareqSha it's the number of times the line was covered. If the report was generated with -covermode=set, the values will only be 0 and 1 as that mode doesn't keep counts. With -covermode=count or -covermode=atomic you can see actual counts.

Comment: @Christian Nuss this should be marked as the correct answer

Answer (score 12):

You process the cover profile using the go `cover` tool:

Open a web browser displaying annotated source code:

```
    go tool cover -html=c.out
```

Write out an HTML file instead of launching a web browser:

```
    go tool cover -html=c.out -o coverage.html
```

Display coverage percentages to stdout for each function:

```
    go tool cover -func=c.out
```

Comment: I'm not seeing ```-html``` or ```-func``` as an option... Am I missing something? http://pastebin.com/d2wgQyDM

Comment: @ChristianNuss: you need to use the cover tool. Use the commands exactly as they are printed in my answer (which is taken directly from `go tool cover -help`)

Comment: Ahh, thanks, First run go test -coverprofile, and then run go tool cover on that output file.  Still, is there a way to convert the raw cover output file into another format, preferably xunit?

Comment: @ChristianNuss: I'm not aware of any translators. The mailing list would probably be the best place to ask if anyone has written one.

Comment: Useful comment from the forums: I need to try each out but the tools seem viable: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-nuts/iUc68Zrxk_c

Comment: `go tool cover -h`